# How to send file attachment to WhatsApp Web using puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, whatsapp, headless-browser

I am currently working on integrating WhatsApp functionality into my application, specifically using the WhatsApp Web URL to send messages programmatically. How can I send a file attachment using the WhatsApp Web URL?

I am currently using Puppeteer, a Node.js library for controlling headless Chrome or Chromium, to automate sending messages through WhatsApp Web. I have successfully implemented sending text messages using the following WhatsApp Web URL format:

```
const URL=`${WHATSAPP_WEB_URL}send?phone=${number}&text=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;
```

However, I am now facing challenges when it comes to sending file attachments along with the text message. My goal is to attach a file from a given URL to the WhatsApp message. I would like to know:

1. Are there any specific encoding requirements for the attachment parameter value?
2. What is the format or structure of the attachment parameter in the WhatsApp Web URL? Is it a separate URL, a file path, or some other format?
3. Are there any alternative methods or libraries within the Puppeteer ecosystem that can simplify the process of attaching files to WhatsApp messages?